# How to prevent original pandas dataframe changing its value while being referenced in a class object?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, class, object

This is what I expect with Python class. I have a variable `num` with a certain value. The class instance `x` initially calls it, then the class changes its `self.num` value with the function `add_one`. The `num` retains its original value.

```
class Test_Class:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def show(self):
        return self.num

    def add_one(self):
        self.num = self.num+1

num = 50
x = Test_Class(num)
x.add_one()
print (x.show())
print (num)

# Output
# 51
# 50
```

But for some strange reason, I have used the same logic with Pandas dataframe, but it is as though the `obj.df` directly links to the original `df_test`, so that when I changed `obj_df` via `add_new_col`, it also changes the `df_test`. What I want is to have `df_test` not adding the `NEW_COL`.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Col2':[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

class Test_Class:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def add_new_col(self, df, column_name): # this function requires a df as parameter
        df[column_name] = 100

obj = Test_Class(df_test)
obj.add_new_col(obj.df, 'NEW_COL')

print (obj.df)
print (df_test)

# Output
   Col1  Col2  NEW_COL
0     1     3      100
1     2     4      100
2     3     5      100
3     4     6      100
4     5     7      100
   Col1  Col2  NEW_COL
0     1     3      100
1     2     4      100
2     3     5      100
3     4     6      100
4     5     7      100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class' `__init__` method, use the line `self.df = df.copy()` to initiate `self.df` as a *copy* of the original dataframe. If we modify the example you gave, the output is as follows:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Col2':[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

class Test_Class:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df.copy()

    def add_new_col(self, df, column_name): # this function requires a df as parameter
        df[column_name] = 100

obj = Test_Class(df_test)
obj.add_new_col(obj.df, 'NEW_COL')

print (obj.df)
print (df_test)

   Col1  Col2  NEW_COL
0     1     3      100
1     2     4      100
2     3     5      100
3     4     6      100
4     5     7      100

   Col1  Col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
3     4     6
4     5     7
```

Comment: I will try it. But do you mind elaborating what is under the hood, why you need to specify a copy when dealing with dataframe while not the same with other types of variable?

Comment: It's not just Pandas dataframes, if you were to run your experiment with a normal python list, you'd see the same behavior. This is because dataframes and lists are mutable (can be changed) objects in python, while variables like ints or strings are immutable (can't be changed after being created) objects. Here's a nice medium post that should explain in greater depth: https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747